# Not bad to point out that

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases, spoken-english

When I'm near the end of my talk in explaining something, and I remember another (perhaps less important) point, can I continue my sentences like this: "**not bad to  point out/mention/add  that...**"?

I feel like it needs an "it's" in the beginning, but maybe it sound a bit formal that way. As I said i'm trying to say it while talking(not while writing). Do you know of any alternatives for that purpose? I thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: If you're going to say that, definitely say "**It's** not bad to point out that (X, Y and Z.)"  I can't say I hear that phrase often, but the audience would understand. 
Personally I would say something like, "I should also add that..." or "I neglected to mention that..." or "Also keep in mind that..."

Comment: I would use "I might also point out that..." Your example needs "it's", but it seems too passive voice for a speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is worthwhile pointing out" is a useful phrase. Also, start with "finally" (unless you have already done so). It will sound like you've been saving the point till last:

> Finally, it is worthwhile pointing out... blah, blah, blah. (pause) Thank you very much.

One good reason never to begin a remark with "finally" – you may think of another one.

Answer (score 1):

> I should also mention...
>
> Not to mention...
>
> What's (meaning "what is") more...
>
> Moreso...
>
> Also...
>
> Keep in mind that...

All of these and more can tie together a heretofore complete explanation with something additional, more important, or until now omitted or forgotten. The one you select should reflect why the information was omitted.

Such reasons could be because you forgot until now, to contrast with prior information that is perhaps less important or more obvious, to give warning not to forget an important detail of the matter, to summarize, etc. There is no singular idiomatic way to segue like this; rather all of these phrases and more are used in everyday speech.